# differential form identity and permutations

Tags: differential-geometry, permutations, differential-forms

If $t^1,...,t^k$ are the coordinates of a k-cube.

Then apparently

$$dt^{\sigma(1)} \wedge \ldots  \wedge dt^{\sigma(k)}= (\operatorname{sgn} (\sigma)) dt^1 \wedge dt^k $$

I cannot see how this proved, nor does it seem intuitively true.

Comment: Typo which has now been changed

Comment: Well then, a two form is certainly not equal to a k form, unless k = 2. So there is probably a typo in the source you are quoting from, which an editor inadvertently fixed in your first transcription of the question.

Comment: Thanks probably why it didnt look correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider $dt^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dt^k$ as a wedge product of $k$ 1-forms, the conclusion can't be more obvious.

Recall that the wedge product of $k$ $1$-forms:
$$
dt^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dt^k\triangleq\frac{k!}{1!\cdots 1!}\mathcal A(dt^1\otimes\cdots\otimes dt^k).
$$
where $\mathcal A$ is the alternating operator:
$$
\mathcal A(\omega)(v_1,\dots,v_k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum_{\tau\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\tau)\omega(v_{\tau(1)},\dots,v_{\tau(k)}),\forall\text{ vector fields }v_1,\dots,v_k.
$$
As a result of the definition:
$$
\begin{split}
dt^{\sigma(1)}\wedge\cdots\wedge dt^{\sigma(k)}(v_1,\dots,v_k)&=\sum_{\tau\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\tau)dt^{\sigma(1)}\otimes\cdots\otimes dt^{\sigma(k)}(v_{\tau(1)},\dots,v_{\tau(k)})\\
&=\sum_{\tau\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\tau)\text{sgn}(\sigma)^2dt^{1}\otimes\cdots\otimes dt^{k}(v_{\sigma\tau(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma\tau(k)})\\
&=\text{sgn}(\sigma)\sum_{\tau\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma\tau)dt^{1}\otimes\cdots\otimes dt^{k}(v_{\sigma\tau(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma\tau(k)})\\
&=^*\text{sgn}(\sigma)\sum_{\sigma\tau\in S_k}\text{sgn}(\sigma\tau)dt^{1}\otimes\cdots\otimes dt^{k}(v_{\sigma\tau(1)},\dots,v_{\sigma\tau(k)})\\
&\triangleq\text{sgn}(\sigma)dt^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dt^k(v_1,\dots,v_k)
\end{split}
$$
The $=^*$ is true since $\tau\mapsto\sigma\tau$ is a bijective auto map on the permutation group $S_k$ of $k$ elements.

Comment: Does it really require all this formality

Comment: @1234 It does, until you develop a systematic intuition. Thats why beginners do a lot of computation but professionals manipulate abstractness (the abstractness is advanced intuition).

Comment: Could elaborate on what you mean by this

Comment: @1234 If you read a more advanced differential geometry book, you will realize that it is possible to work on a more axiomatic level. You will need to upgrade your knowledge about linear algebra and tensor analysis to do that, maybe also a little category theory. But I'm not sure if you are already ready.